# Remove or Exclude WatchSource in sbt 1.0.x

Tags: scala, playframework, build, sbt

### Overview

After looking around the internet for a while, I have not found a good way to omit certain folders from being watched by `sbt 1.0.x` in a Play Framework application.

### Solutions posted for older versions of `sbt`:

- [How to exclude a folder from compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371618/how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-compilation)
- [How to not watch a file for changes in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003966/how-to-not-watch-a-file-for-changes-in-play-framework)
- There are a few more, but all more or less the same.

And the release notes for `1.0.2` show that the `+=` and `++=` behavior was maintained, but everything else was dropped.

- https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html
- Source code verifies: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0.4/api/sbt/Watched$.html

---

Would love to see if anyone using `sbt 1.0.x` has found a solution or workaround to this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this - just upgraded to 1.0.4 and having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the approach of how SBT [excludes](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/cc0dc0c9037eea25ff77d1081a9c4584823fcab3/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L357) `managedSources` from `watchSources` I was able to omit a custom folder from being watched like so:

```
watchSources := {
  val directoryToExclude = "/Users/mgalic/sandbox/scala/scala-seed-project/src/main/scala/dirToExclude"
  val filesToExclude = (new File(directoryToExclude) ** "*.scala").get.toSet
  val customSourcesFilter = new FileFilter {
    override def accept(pathname: File): Boolean = filesToExclude.contains(pathname)
    override def toString = s"CustomSourcesFilter($filesToExclude)"
  }

  watchSources.value.map { source =>
    new Source(
      source.base,
      source.includeFilter,
      source.excludeFilter || customSourcesFilter,
      source.recursive
    )
  }
},
```

Here we use [`PathFinder`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Paths.html#Selecting+descendants) to get all the `*.scala` sources from `directoryToExclude`:

```
val filesToExclude = (new File(directoryToExclude) ** "*.scala").get.toSet
```

Then we create `customSourcesFilter` using `filesToExclude`, which we then add to every current `WatchSource`:

```
  watchSources.value.map { source =>
    new Source(
      ...
      source.excludeFilter || customSourcesFilter,
      ...
    )
  }
```

Note the above solution is just something that worked for me, that is, I do not know what is the recommend approach of solving this problem.

Comment: This did not quite work for me, but I really appreciate the answer.