# How to use WatchSource in SBT 1.x to filter files?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I had the following code like the following that worked previously:

```
.settings(watchSources := watchSources.value.filterNot(_.getPath.contains("target")))
```

In SBT 1.x this results in:

```
error: value getPath is not a member of sbt.Watched.WatchSource
x.getPath.contains("target")
```

Expanding the code slightly by adding a type to the function paramemter of `filterNot`:

```
.settings(watchSources := (watchSources.value.filterNot{x: File =>
  x.getPath.contains("target")
}))
```

we get a separate error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/brandon/workspace/CCRS/project
/home/brandon/workspace/CCRS/build.sbt:111: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.File => Boolean
    (which expands to)  java.io.File => Boolean
 required: sbt.Watched.WatchSource => Boolean
    (which expands to)  sbt.internal.io.Source => Boolean
  .settings(watchSources := watchSources.value.filterNot{x: File =>
                                                             ^
```

The strange thing is that IntelliJ seems to think the code looks fine as is (I did restart IntelliJ after updating my `build.properties` with the latest version of SBT) - it sees the value `x` as a `File`, not as a `WatchSource`, and it indicates that `watchSources.value` is of type `Seq[File]`.

This related but more general question ( [Remove or Exclude WatchSource in sbt 1.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653295/remove-or-exclude-watchsource-in-sbt-1-0-x) ) doesn't seem to have garnered any attention thus far.

Comment: `Source`'s `base: File` constructor parameter has been changed to be a `val` recently, but unfortunately the patched version appears not to be released yet: https://github.com/sbt/io/pull/123/commits/3564f5050c9c93bb4b80c45f45029a507fcefa66

Comment: Thanks, sounds vaguely promising, but I'm woefully ignorant of SBT, so I don't understand the direct implications.

Comment: I can confirm it isn't an issue in 0.13.7, and happily everything else in my build setup also works with 0.13.7

Comment: Yes, the situation can be explained as follows: `WatchSources` is of type `TaskKey[Seq[File]]` in 0.13 while it is of type `TaskKey[Seq[WatchSource]]` in 1.x. `WatchSource` is an alias of `sbt.internal.io.Source`, which did not allow us to access its `File` component, `base`, until recently.

Comment: Any updates on this - just upgraded to 1.0.4 and having trouble.

Comment: @dkim you said it didn't allow us to access the `File` component, `base`, until recently. Does that mean this is fixed now? (e.g. in sbt 1.2.x) It would be useful if this question could be answered taking into account recent changes in sbt

Comment: @BenMcCann Thank you for reminding me. According to GitHub, the commit above has been incorporated into sbt 1.2.0. So I think that the OP's code can be written now as follows: `.settings(watchSources := watchSources.value.filterNot(_.base.getPath.contains("target")))`

Comment: So far, the above code seems to compile (using sbt 1.2.8). I'll just note that some recent versions of IntelliJ flag it as erroneous, while it is not. I'm revisiting all of this again and need to check to see if my other SBT errors were fixed in another branch! Thanks.